# PySpark pandas udf last task blocked

Tags: pandas, pyspark, pyarrow

I am working to tuning a simple spark job like
data.groupby(key cols).applyInPandas(python UDF).

but the stage to enhance the UDF always blocked in the last task.
I am very sure the function logic run over by task log.
but the status is still running.

add details of UDF, in the UDF, I just transform pandas into Pyarrow table and use another C++ so lib read the arrow table.then return a pandas.
After some research, I found that when i reduce the amount of data transform into Pyarrow table, job succeeded. and the Thread dump log of the task always runing indicates that it seems locked in Java.io.BufferinputStream. so I guess that if  the arrow table in UDF occupied too many memory.

Anyone know something about it ?

Add blocked task thread dump picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c22Sj.png)

the root casue or the way to solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.